# How do I combine two objects into one in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs4

I have a G and an arrow. I want the arrow to act as the horizontal portion of the G. I have it lined up but when I apply effects I want then to act in one. For example If I apply a 3d effect I want the arrow and the G to go 3d and look like one object not two.

how do I combine the G and the arrow (created on a path) into one object using Illustrator CS4?

Comment: I must say that this question cannot be called useful altogether. Combining shapes is a basic in Illustrator and not knowing that shows lack of research.

Answer (score 52):

First you will have to convert the arrow from a path / stroke into a shape object. Do this by selecting `Object -> Path -> Outline Stroke`.

Open the Pathfinder palette (`Window -> Pathfinder`) and with the two items selected `alt-click` on the `Unite` button - it’s the first one that looks like two squares united into one.

[image]

Comment: when i converted the path into a shape object i lost the arrow heads. the arrow heads were added by using effect > Stylize > Arrow heads

Comment: OK - with the line selected go to Object > Expand Appearance. This will create a separate shape for the arrowhead. You should then make the (headless) line a shape using Outline Stroke, giving you three objects. Then alt-click the Unite button to unify the three shape elements.

Comment: Thanks Man. I was using "Make Compound Path" to united two objects but when outlining them with stroke, it appeared around all the objects. But with Pathfinder>Unite I just have one object to work with. +1

Answer (score 2):

1. PATHFINDER PALETTE / ADD TO SHAPE AREA
2. OBJECT MENU / EXPAND APPEARANCE

Always do this with objects selected.

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the shapebuilder tool after outlining the stroke

Comment: Interestingly, I found your answer the most helpful, but that was because I was using CS6.  If you notice, this question is about CS4 and the ShapeBuilder tool doesn't exist in CS4.  You might want to consider removing your comment on the question, as well.